# Difference in quality when video is uploaded directly from camera and when it is selected from gallery

Tags: ios, iphone, video, uiimagepickercontroller

**Problem**

- I am currently developing an iPhone app, where I need to upload a video with a multipart post request.
- I am using AfNetworking and UIImagePickerController.
- I set the quality of the UIImagePickerController to high.
- When I try to upload a video that has just been recorded in the app, the quality is significantly lower, than when I choose a previously recorded video from the gallery.

**Question**

Does anybody have experience like this one ?